# How can I use Recursive CTE to find all products that were purchased together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'm working on a problem that requires to find all possible items that were purchased together in past matching the order at hand. The store has a large selection of items, and the customer could purchase any number of items together (i.e. 1 to N products). I've to find all items that were purchased together (including items purchased alone) in past which matches the current order in terms of items and qty ordered. If exact quantities can't be found then find the closest group.

```
DECLARE @SampleData as TABLE (OrderID int, Item varchar(20) , PurchaseQty int)

INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (1       ,'Shirt'      ,2)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (1       ,'Shoes'      ,1)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (2       ,'Shirt'      ,4)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (2       ,'Pant'       ,1)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (2       ,'Shoes'      ,1)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (3      ,'T-Shirt'     ,3)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (3      ,'Short'       ,2)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (4      ,'Shirt'       ,1)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (5      ,'Shoes'       ,3)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (5      ,'Shirt'       ,1)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (5      ,'Pant'        ,1)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (5      ,'Tie'         ,1)
```

e.g. if the current order is for `(2 shirt, 1 shoes)`, I'like to find all orders that have either of these or both in it. So from above data, the result should be like `OrderId 1,2,5 and 4` since they have either or both of these items. Notice the sequence of orders is to match the exact and then the next closet.

I've tried following recursive CTE, but it is entering endless recursion and crashing:

```
;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT sd.OrderID, sd.Item, sd.PurchaseQty
   FROM @SampleData sd 
   WHERE sd.Item in ('shirt','short')
   UNION ALL
   SELECT sd.OrderID, t.Item, sd.PurchaseQty
   FROM @SampleData sd
   INNER JOIN temp t ON t.item = sd.Item
)
SELECT * FROM temp t 
Order By t.PurchaseQty
```

Althogh in this case, I've selected `(shirt,shoes)` as a possible order, customer can order any number of items in any qty, e.g. an order of 35 distinct items. I've to find either an order having the exact match in terms of items and qty, or the closet match. e.g. if it can't find an order with 2 shirts and 1 shoe, find an order with 1 shirt and 1 shoe etc.

Is recursive CTE the correct type of query for such a problem, if yes, how can I achieve it.

Comment: Please provide a _precise_ definition for "closest". How should ties, if any, be resolved?

Comment: With closest, I mean any prior purchase that has all the purchased items in it in the same quantity as the current order, or as close to the current order qty as possible. Say if current order (e.g. 4 shirts, 3 shoes) can't be found in prior purchases, find (3 shirts, 3 shoes) or (4 shirts, 2 shoes). If that can't be found, find (2 shirts 3 shoes) or (4 shirts 2 shoes) etc. It is like finding all combinations of all items ordered in all qty less or equal to current order in decreasing priority.

Comment: You didn't address ties. If the current order is 4 shirts/3 shoes and approximate matches are found with 3/3 and 4/2 which of those is closest? Is it 3/3 because the drop from 4 to 3 is only 25% while 4/2 has a drop of 33% from 3 to 2? Is it weighted by the price of the items? The width of the shoes? Chosen at random?

Comment: 3/3 and 4/2 are both similar priority whichever is found first should appear first. Other attributes like weighted by price/size etc. doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need a recursive query. A simple self-join with EXISTS will work:

```sql
select * from @SampleData s
where exists
( select * from @SampleData q
  where q.OrderId = s.OrderID
    and q.Item in ('Shirt','Shoes') )
```

If the number of items in the current order is large, you may want to put the current order in a temp table ##CurrentOrder and join to it in the inner query:

```sql
select * from @SampleData s
where exists
( select * from @SampleData q
  where q.OrderId = s.OrderID
    and q.Item in (select Item from ##CurrentOrder) )
```

Comment: Simple join would work if we assume that the order is as given. What if the item list is bounded by all the items the store is carrying and customer can order any combination of items.

Comment: It still works, just use another table like the ##CurrentOrder I added to my answer.

Comment: You would only need a recursive query if you want to keep adding items to the same set. For example, with a recursive query, if you had an order 6 with pants and gloves, that would then be added because order 5 added pants, liking 5 that is already in your set to 6.

Comment: And what can I do about the quantities. I.e. if the exact qty match can't be found, find the closest match in terms of items and qty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use STRING_AGG with the Distinct values.
the SElection of the order happens in the subselect, as STRINg_AGG doesn't support DISTINCT

> ```
> CREATE tABLE  SampleData  (OrderID int, Item varchar(20) , PurchaseQty int)
>
> INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (1       ,'Shirt'      ,2)
> INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (1       ,'Shoes'      ,1)
> INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (2       ,'Shirt'      ,4)
> INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (2       ,'Pant'       ,1)
> INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (2       ,'Shoes'      ,1)
> INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (3      ,'T-Shirt'     ,3)
> INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (3      ,'Short'       ,2)
> INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (4      ,'Shirt'       ,1)
> INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (5      ,'Shoes'       ,1)
> INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (5      ,'Pant'        ,1)
> INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (5      ,'Tie'         ,1)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> STRING_AGG(orderID,',')
> WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY OrderID ASC )
> FROM
> (SELECT DISTINCT orderID   FROM SampleData WHERE Item IN ('shirt', 'shoes')) t1
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 1,2,4,5          |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b609ef79d72a4f3ab3277d2773e5ac7)*

Comment: Can these be ordered in terms of closet item/qty match?

Comment: For that you need to join another subquery, and join it to t1